# Get usage statistic of 301 redirects

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, redirect

I'm using Google's Webmaster Tools as well as some handmade script that logs 404s into a DB to get all wrong links and put the results into a corrected 301 redirect in my .htaccess-file.

It seems that the .htaccess grows and grows, which surely reasons from another problem which I can't influence at the moment.

I was wondering though (to keep the size of the .htaccess as small as possible for readability), whether there's a tool or any method to track the usage of those redirects?!

So after a while I might be able to take them out when they aren't neccessary anymore, in the course of Googles index-update and my own changes to faulty links. Any ideas?

Comment: `.htaccess` should small not only for readability but also server optimization. What idea to use php or cgi to do the job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should rewrite any unservable requests to a PHP script to handle this, then you can do whatever you what with the data.

In your .htaccess add (after any other rewrite rules you have in place):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* /404.php?uri=$0 [L]
```

And in `404.php` do something like this (semi-pseudocode):

```
// Get the redirect mapping for this URI from the database
$query = "
    SELECT location
    FROM redirects
    WHERE uri = ?
";
$redirect = $db->query($query, $_GET['uri']);

if ($redirect) {
    // Update database with tracking data
    $query = "
        UPDATE redirects
        SET
          hits = hits + 1,
          lastHit = NOW()
        WHERE uri = ?
    ";
    $db->query($query, $_GET['uri']);

    // Do the redirect
    header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 301 Moved Permanently');
    header('Location: ' . $redirect);
} else {
    // Really not found
    header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 404 Not Found');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For keeping the .htaccess small, you could use [`RewriteMap`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap), see [`txt`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html#txt) or [`dbm`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html#dbm) for example.

The Apache `access.log` should already track the requests. To see, if the links are still used, you can compare the entries in `access.log` with the `RewriteMap` text file.

For easier comparison, you could also add an additional [`CustomLog`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html#customlog), tracking only the URL path

```
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/tracker.log %U
```

or

```
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/tracker.log "%U %t"
```

if you need the access time as well.